# why gdb show wrong variable value?

Tags: c, gdb

I have simple program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int i) {
    i = 1;
    printf("%d\n", i);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    func(0);
    return 0;
}
```

and now:

```
gcc test.c -g -o test

gdb test
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x400543: file test.c, line 9.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /tmp/test 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe458) at test.c:9
9       func(0);
(gdb) s
func (i=0) at test.c:4
4       i =1;
(gdb) p i
$1 = 0
(gdb) n
5       printf("%d\n", i);
(gdb) p i
$2 = 0
(gdb)
```

Program works fine, shows "1", but why gdb shows me "0" value?

Debian wheezy.

I observed that on gcc-4.7, gcc-4.6.
On gcc-4.4 all is ok.

Comment: what does `printf` print?

Comment: It works for me.  The second `p i`: `(gdb) p i
$2 = 1`

Comment: @Mat - OP's example shows no optimizations.

Comment: GNU gdb (GDB) 7.4.1-debian

Comment: Could it be `gdb test` loads the wrong binary? Did you try `gdb ./test` ...?

Comment: gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a bug that is fixed if you compile with `-fvar-tracking`.  Your question is a tighter version of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734078/gdb-prints-wrong-values-when-modifying-arguments), which references a [bug report on GCC 4.8.0](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54218) suggesting the above compile flag.