# How to debug input variables

Tags: c++, debugging, mingw, eclipse-neon

I'm trying to use Eclipse with C++, MinGW compiler, to debug some really simple programs, but i can't find a way to make it work, whenever i input a variable by keyboard, it changes it to a random 40-50 number.

It's probably because of my lack of knowledge but my classmates were having trouble aswell so i wanted to make sure we were doing it 'right'.

[image: ## Example ##]

Comment: @John3136: It's an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: Is it still random if you initialize `i` to `0`? Is the breakpoint on line 39? What happens if you put it on line 40?

Comment: does cout print the correct int (3)? I'm guessing line 39 hasnt been run yet.

Comment: @Erix If i execute it normally, it works just fine, ut just gives troubles on debug mode

Comment: @DanMašek Yeah, but not instead of 49-51, it goes to 60-70

Comment: @DanMašek And nothing changes if i put the breakpoint on line 40

Comment: maybe similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14734078/gdb-prints-wrong-values-when-modifying-arguments